# If I have a binary classificator and I run it several times, can I interpret the mean of the results as an probability?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models

I have a binary classificator that predicts the occurrence of an event.

If I run it multiple times and do the mean of all results, can I interpret that as a probability of the event happening?

Lets say 4 of them return 1, meaning the event will occur, and the other 6 predict a 0, is it reasonable to interpret that as a 40% chance of the event occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many models that are designed to predict this probability directly: Logistic Regression, Gradient Boosting, etc.  Why not use one of these models instead of running a hard classifier multiple times and averaging?

Answer (score 3):

If you care about retrieving probabilities, then you should use a method that yields probabilities directly, rather than relying on some *ad hoc* procedure. Common examples are [logistic-regression](/questions/tagged/logistic-regression), [random-forest](/questions/tagged/random-forest), [neural-networks](/questions/tagged/neural-networks), [xgboost](/questions/tagged/xgboost).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Sycorax.  Consider that what you're actually measuring by doing this is variation in your *model* rather than variation in your target, and conflating the two is dangerous.

Suppose for example that we have a binary classification problem and a model which is a perfect oracle, i.e., it knows the true probabilities for all examples.  Our model always predicts the most likely event no matter how many times we run it, but if we average these results we will only get zeros and ones, which obviously should *not* be interpreted as probabilities.